# OTRS: After closing tickets, customers don't get notification

Tags: otrs

I installed OTRS 4.0.6 and connected with AD. All the processes run successfully but when an agent close the tickets, the closing notification doesn't reach respective customers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. 
http://wiki.otterhub.org/index.php?title=Notify_Users_that_a_Ticket_has_closed

Closure notifications don't come in by default. You need to configure notification emails.

Comment: You should explain what is under the link so that your answer does not become useless once it goes down.